# OS X 10.8.2 renders blurry screen with slight vertical stripes on my new Dell monitor

Tags: macos, mac, display, resolution

When I visit System Preferences > Displays and change the refresh rate from 60Hz to 75Hz, then hit revert suddenly the display becomes clear and sharp. Selecting scaled resolution as opposed to "best for display" and than changing to different resolution and back also works.

However the fix is not permanent as blur and stripes come back whenever the computer wakes up from sleep.

How can I fix this permanently?

Comment: Is your computer connected by a VGA or other type of cable (DVI, HDMI, DP)?

Answer (score 0):

Tried the temp fix again (see my question) and restarted the computer, everything looked fine after restart.
I put the mac to sleep again and woke it up. Problem obviously reappeared.

Despite previous failures, I tried the temp fix one more time and restarted the computer, now I put it to sleep and woke it up. To my surprise the problem appears solved.

I feel like the setting had a problem getting written into a configuration file. Could anyone comment on what is the xorg.conf equivalent on a mac?

I do use Mini Display Port to VGA Adapter by Apple.